# nchar retrieved from DB as Null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm retrieving a row from the DB to display a citizen. I have a column for marital status that is defined in the DB as `nchar(1)` and as `char?` in the model:

```
[DisplayName("Marital Status")]
public char? mrtlStt { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mrtlSttOptns
{
    get {
       return new[] { new SelectListItem {Value="m", Text="Married" },
                      new SelectListItem {Value="d", Text="Divorced" },
                      new SelectListItem {Value="s", Text="Single" },
                      new SelectListItem {Value="w", Text="Widow" },
                      new SelectListItem {Value="u", Text="Unknown" }};
        }
}
```

In the constructor I did the following:

```
ctzn = new Citizen
                {
                   //additional properties
                    mrtlStt = dr["ctznMrtlStt"] as char?,
                   //additional properties
                };
```

While debugging I noticed that `mrtlStt` is always returned as `null` which is why the dropdown list always shows "please choose marital status" and never the actual marital status. When creating a new `Citizen`, the marital status column is updated properly.

I tried to use the `.ToString()`, casting (char?), CAST inside the stored procedure, but to no avail. Reader functions weren't much help either.

I could change the data type to `nvarchar(1)` and be done with it, but I can't and in any case am intrigued to know why `mrtlStt` is retrieved as `null`.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE: this is the stored procedure.

```
SELECT ctznId, ctznLname, ctznFname, ctznDob, ctznHgt, ctznEml, ctznPhone, ctznNumchilds,
            ctznLivestat, ctznMrtlStt, ctznCtcod, ctznNote
    FROM tblCitizens 
    WHERE tblCitizens.ctznId=@id
```

UPDATE: storing a newly created citizen

```
 public static bool addCitizen(//additional properties, char? mrtlStt, //additional properties)
 {
     bool rslt = false;
     SqlConnection cnctn = new   SqlConnection(Models.DataModels.DataGlobals.cnctnstrng);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = cnctn;
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.CommandText = "addCitizen";
     //adding parameters 
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@mrtlStt", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar, 1);
     //adding parameters;
     try
     {
         cnctn.Open();
         ...
         cmd.Parameters["@mrtlStt"].Value = mrtlStt;
         ...
         int rc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (rc == 1)
             rslt = true;
     }
     catch
     {

     }
```

Creation Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addCitizen]
...
@fmlstt as nchar(1)=N'u',
...
AS
BEGIN
   begin try
    INSERT INTO tblCitizens(... ,ctznMrtlStt, ...) 
        VALUES (..., @mrtlStt, ...)
    return @@rowcount
end try
begin catch -- if ID exists
    return 0
end catch      
END
```

Comment: Are you sure its the retrieval problem and the data stored correctly in the database?

Comment: @marc_s, yeah sorry about that :(

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm pretty sure it's in the retrieval stage. When I put a break point and went over all the properties, each had the respective and correct value save for 'mrtlStt' that was null.

Comment: Well you're sure at the code level, but you don't know if it gets saved to Db or not. May be because of some type casting at the time of saving converts it to NULL? Please show the code when you save it too.

Comment: @Shaharyar I have Sql Server Management Studio open at all times and I often check the records and they are updated properly. There are no null cells in the column. I updated to include the creation code block.

Answer (score 2):

Gotta love programming!

Just one of those little conversion vs. casting and messing around with data types.

So,

```
mrtlStt = dr["ctznMrtlStt"] as char?,
```

Should be

```
Convert.ToChar(dr["ctznMrtlStt"]),
```

That's it. It wasn't retrieved as null, the use of `as` in casting returns null when the object is not of the same type.

Many thanks for comments made in this post and many thanks to those who edited my post to make it clearer.